# Adding Cheerio.js to an Angular 6 project?

Tags: angular, cheerio

I created a brand-new Angular 6 project and installed Cheerio.js:

`npm install cheerio`

Once Cheerio.js was installed, I figured all I had to do to add it to my project was to import it and add it to the NgModule imports:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    cheerio
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

However, after doing this, I'm getting a TypeScript error, something along the line of "Could not find a declaration file for module 'cheerio'."

Am I going about this the wrong way? I just need to be able to parse some HTML within the Angular app and read that Cheerio.js was the way to go.

Comment: Why not jQuery? The Angular app will have a window object. Cheerio is a workaround for when that's not available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't add `cheerio` inside `imports` of your `NgModule`, basically `imports` array takes an Angular application module name, where in you wanted to use third party library inside angular application.

Basically you should add `cheerio` file reference inside your `angular.json` file `scripts` option. This will ensure that `cheerio` plugin is loaded inside your bundle file. It is ready to use now.

```
"scripts": [
  ...,
  "node_modules/cheerio/lib/cheerio.js"
]
```

Then to use `cheerio` plugin function inside you Angular code. But you should also install `cheerio` typings, such that typescript would not complain against it.

```
npm i -D @types/cheerio
```

Comment: Thanks! Was beating myself up trying to figure this out. I'll mark the answer as soon as the timer is up.

Comment: @Kevin Great, glad to see it helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You also need to install cheerio types npm install --save @types/cheerio